# Can you do overloading in C and have the same function name?

Tags: c, overloading

In Java we can do overloading when the method has the same name. And I was googling and it said that C doesn't support Overloading, so I was wondering is there a way to do something similar to overloading in C .

For example:

```
int max(int num1, int num2);
double max(double num1, num2);

int main(){
  printf(...);
  printf(...);
}

int max(int num1, int num2){
  ...
}

double max(double num1, double num2){
  ...
}
```

Comment: "it said that C doesn't support Overloading". Are you asking for confirmation of what you have already found? What you found is correct - there is no function overloading in C.

Comment: @kaylum Yes I know there is no overloading function in C but is there a way to do it is what I'm asking

Comment: You can give the functions slightly different names, i.e. `int_max` and `double_max`.

Comment: Do what? There is no overloading in C so no you can't do it. But if you are asking for some aspect of overloading then please be more clear about what that is. "something similar" isn't clear. What you could do for example is something like what `printf` does. Using vaargs you can have a first arg that specifies the type of subsequent args. But  your question is not clear enough for us to be sure whether that falls into the category of "something similar"

Answer (score 8):

The reference you found is correct: C does not support overloading, as such.

What it does have (assuming we're talking about the actual C and not historic versions) is a generic selector which allows you to write your own macro which does dynamic dispatch.

C99 introduced the [`tgmath.h`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/tgmath) header, which allows for certain math functions to be overloaded for use with different width floating point arguments, and in some cases complex arguments. However, no facility was introduced in C99 which allowed that feature to be generalised to other functions. The generic selector, introduced in C11, is that facility.

The selector has the form `_Generic(select-expression, type-associations)`, where `type-associations` consists of a comma-separated list of pairs of the form `type : expression`. The selector will be replaced with the expression corresponding to the type of `select-expression`. One of the `type`s can be the keyword `default`; the other ones have to be unique complete types (i.e. no two types in the list can be compatible) [Note 1]. It's important to note that *all* of the expressions in the association list must compile without errors, not just the one eventually selected. Usually, the expressions will be function pointers, rather than function calls.

An example might make this more clear. Suppose we have the two functions (which have different names, so this is not name overloading):

```
int max_int(int a, int b) { return a > b ? a : b; }
double max_dbl(double a, double b) { return a > b ? a : b; }
```

Now, we can define the macro MAX:

```
#define MAX(a, b) _Generic((a)+(b),          \
                    int : max_int,           \
                    double : max_dbl)(a, b)
```

Here, I use `a+b` as the selector expression rather than `a`, because the type of `a+b` is the type which results from the usual arithmetic conversions. If I'd just used `a`, then `MAX(3, 5.7)` would produce an unexpected result, because the generic selector would have selected `max_int` and `5.7` would be silently truncated to 5. With `a+b`, the type of the selector will be `double`, resulting in a call to `max_dbl`, for which both values are converted to double.

I can get away with using `(a)+(b)` in the macro because `_Generic` does not evaluate the selector expression (like `sizeof`). So there's no danger of double evaluation of arguments with side effects.

---

#### Notes:

1. The type of a generic association cannot be a VLA (variable length array), even if the compiler implements them. But any other complete type is fine, even a pointer to an incomplete type.